# variable parameters in C# when function has another function

Tags: c#, debugging

I am sure this has already been answered and I am sorry if I didn't know what to ask to find it properly, but I am very new to C# so please don't flame me as this is a very basic question.

I have learned some python and I would like to create a function like a print statement in python, or like this:

```
public static void PRINT(string d)
{
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d);
}
```

So that I don't have to constantly write Debug.WriteLine() all the time. It will be as simple as my python print statement that I am used to. Buuut. I cannot seem to pass in multiple parameters

```
PRINT("Elapsed Time: {0}..ChangeDelayTime: {1}..CurrentSprite: {2}", elapsedTime, changeDelayedTime, currentSprite);
```

Now I have learned about overloads and that I can make another PRINT function in C# as an overload, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way. (As an aside, I have found something called ArgIterator structure that sounds promising. What is that used for? I tried passing that as a parameter to no avail. )

Comment: Welcome to SO, we don't flame!  Are you just trying to send in multiple strings?  You can just concatenate within the method's parameter.

Comment: If you do want to add an overload, take a look at the [params keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).  There's a corresponding overload to [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153.aspx) that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative method:

```
void Main(){
    Print("{0}, {1}", "test", "another test");
}

void Print(string format, params string[] args){
 Console.WriteLine(format, args);
}
```

output:

> test, another test

Comment: Ok, after playing around with the code and documentation I understand what you are saying. What I don't understand is what the first "string format" is for. Doesn't "params string[] args" work just fine for any string that may be passed? Secondly, why wouldn't one just put "params object[] args" instead?

Comment: yes, it will work. But then you won't have more advanced formatting options (like using text in it) available. You can, but do you want to? If you're okay with someone passing in custom objects, by all means go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
PRINT(string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0}..ChangeDelayTime: {1}..CurrentSprite: {2}", 
          elapsedTime, 
          changeDelayedTime,
          currentSprite));
```

which will pass the formatted string into the function

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this;

```
PRINT(string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0}..ChangeDelayTime: {1}..CurrentSprite: {2}", elapsedTime, changeDelayedTime, currentSprite));
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're missing a call to `string.Format()`. So change it to:

```
PRINT(string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0}..ChangeDelayTime: {1}..CurrentSprite: {2}", elapsedTime, changeDelayedTime, currentSprite));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do is just concatenate within the method's parameter.

For the following method:

```
public static void PRINT(string d)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d);
}
```

You can pass in multiple variables as long as you concatenate such as in the following:

```
TimeSpan elapsedTime;
TimeSpan changedDelayedTime;
string current sprite;
PRINT("Elapsed Time: " + elapsedTime + "..ChangeDelayTime: " + changedDelayTime + "..CurrentSprite: " + currentSprite);
```